# PostgreSQL row inserting CTE with extra returning fields

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.3

Long time reader first time asker here!

In my database, I have the following (simplified) sample tables with some example data,

```sql
create table file_zips (file_id int, zip varchar(5), total int);
create table zip_collections (id serial primary key, zips varchar(5)[]);

insert into file_zips select 1, 66211, 4;
insert into file_zips select 1, 66212, 17;

insert into file_zips select 2, 66101, 1;

insert into file_zips select 3, 66600, 2;
insert into file_zips select 3, 66601, 2;
insert into file_zips select 3, 66602, 2;

insert into file_zips select 4, 66600, 1;
```

What I'd like to do is insert a row in **zip_collections** for **file_zip**.*zip* grouped on *file_id* and then create a new table, **file_collections**, populated with the *file_id* and the *zip_collection_id* of the rows that were inserted. It seemed like a good use of a Common Table Expression, but I haven't been able to get it to work quite right.

Here's what I tried to write,

```sql
with w as (
  insert into zip_collections (zips) 
  select array_agg(zip)
  from file_zips
  group by file_id
  returning id, file_id
)
select id as zip_collection_id, file_id
into file_collections
from w;
```

The query fails to execute, I can't have *file_id* in the returning clause of the insert because it isn't part of **zip_collections**. Is there a way to compose this query without temporarily adding a *file_id* column to **zip_collections**?

Here is a link to a SQL Fiddle Sample

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e72f3/6

Thank you for your time!

*Edit: I expanded on the sample data. Here's some example of the output I'm expecting.*

file_collections

```
|zip_collection_id|file_id|
|1|1|
|2|2|
|3|3|
|4|4|
```

zip_collections

```
|zip_collection_id|zips|
|1|66211,66212|
|2|66101|
|3|66600,66601,66602|
|4|66600|
```

Comment: I forgot the group by statement in the sample, thanks to Martin Strejc for noticing! I expanded the sample data and added samples of what the expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your case doesn't make a sense without grouping zip by file id. So just add grouping and the file_id into the table 'zip_collections' should be enough.

**Structure and init**

```
create table file_zips (file_id int, zip varchar(5), total int);
create table zip_collections (id serial primary key, zips varchar(5)[], file_id int);

insert into file_zips select 1, 66211, 4;
insert into file_zips select 1, 66212, 17;
```

**SQL:**

```
with w as (
  insert into zip_collections (zips, file_id) 
  select array_agg(zip), file_id
  from file_zips group by file_id
  returning id, file_id
)
select id as zip_collection_id, file_id
into file_collections
from w;

select * from file_collections;
```

Comment: While there's a fair chance this is exactly what I'm going to end up doing, my question was whether there was a way to write this query _without adding file_id to zip_collections_.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-insert.html) states that the columns returned by the insert need to be actually inserted columns:

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted.

You can always join it back in some way like below and get the `file_id` that way:

```
with w as (
   insert into zip_collections (zips) 
   select array_agg(zip)
   from file_zips
   returning id, zips
)
select w.id as zip_collection_id, z.file_id
into file_collections
from w
left join file_zips z on w.zips[1] = z.zip
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sorry but I had a mistake in the example query when you wrote this and have since clarified it.